# How do I use a valid OAuth2 access token with the NodeJS SDK for the Google People API

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

I'm not understand either the Google docs or the code documentation for how to use an access token with a method from the googleapis people module.

My use case is to get a user's phone number for account creation in my application.  I accept the access token and validate it and check its scope, as outlined in the Google documentation here: [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Step 4 in that document says "Send the access token to an API" - and then they outline the process for including it in a header.  But I'm using the NodeJS SDK, so I'm trying to figure out how to pass the access token to either my `people` constructor or the method proper.

Starting with the method proper, my parameters seem to be `personFields`, `resourceName`, and `sources` - none of which are suitable for the access token.

So I looked at the `people` constructors:

```js
export declare function people(version: 'v1'): people_v1.People;
export declare function people(options: people_v1.Options): people_v1.People;
```

I note that the second extends GlobalOptions with the version property.  GlobalOptions extends MethodOptions (and so on) with the auth property.  Which seems right (at least in name).  I see that the auth property's type is:

```js
auth?: GoogleAuth | OAuth2Client | BaseExternalAccountClient | string;
```

Of these types, it seems like `string` would be my target - but there's no good documentation as to what it wanted there.

What am I missing - where do I input this access token?  In the people_v1 section that details the people_v1 options, I see there's an interface called StandardParameters - and access_token is right there!  But I can't figure out WHY it's right there or how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple test sample for Oauth Client that might help:

```
/**
 * Simple Oauth Test to make sure that the Oauth flow is working,
 * Does NOT store tokens.
 */

'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const opn = require('open');
const destroyer = require('server-destroy');

const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');
const people = google.people('v1');

/**
 * To use OAuth2 authentication, we need access to a CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, AND REDIRECT_URI.  To get these credentials for your application, visit https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials.
 */
const keyPath = path.join(__dirname, 'private/client_secret.....apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
let keys = {
  redirect_uris: ['']
};
if (fs.existsSync(keyPath)) {
  keys = require(keyPath).web;
}

/**
 * Create a new OAuth2 client with the configured keys.
 */
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  keys.client_id,
  keys.client_secret,
  keys.redirect_uris[0]
);

/**
 * This is one of the many ways you can configure googleapis to use authentication credentials.  In this method, we're setting a global reference for all APIs.  Any other API you use here, like google.drive('v3'), will now use this auth client. You can also override the auth client at the service and method call levels.
 */
google.options({
  auth: oauth2Client
});

/**
 * Open an http server to accept the oauth callback. In this simple example, the only request to our webserver is to /callback?code=<code>
 */
async function authenticate(scopes) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // grab the url that will be used for authorization
    const authorizeUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: scopes.join(' '),
    });
    const server = http
      .createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
          if (req.url.indexOf('/oauth2callback') > -1) {
            const qs = new url.URL(req.url, 'http://localhost:3000')
              .searchParams;
            res.end('Authentication successful! Please return to the console.');
            server.destroy();
            const {
              tokens
            } = await oauth2Client.getToken(qs.get('code'));
            oauth2Client.credentials = tokens; // eslint-disable-line require-atomic-updates
            resolve(oauth2Client);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      })
      .listen(3000, () => {
        // open the browser to the authorize url to start the workflow
        opn(authorizeUrl, {
          wait: false
        }).then(cp => cp.unref());
      });
    destroyer(server);
  });
}

async function runSample() {
  // retrieve user profile
  const res = await people.people.get({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    personFields: 'emailAddresses',
  });
  console.log(res.data);
}

const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read',
  'profile',
];


async function test() {
  let client = await authenticate(scopes);
  await runSample(client);
}

test();
```

Use your own 'private/client_secret.....apps.googleusercontent.com.json' and it should work.